# How to have shader=interp gradient follow a different direction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, shading

The shading of the interp option in 3D surface plots always has vertically shifting gradients.

Is there a way to obtain horizontal gradients?

Example image below, only instead imagine the right side of the sphere to start out white and transition to black on the antipodal point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=2pt}]

    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.65, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({-x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{-x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{-x});
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(0,0,0)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani window underlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%viviani cylinder parts
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(100,100,100)rgb255=(255,255,255)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {min(-sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(255,255,255)rgb255=(100,100,100)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {max(sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
%viviani window overlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=-pi/3:2*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=5*pi/3:8*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=2.34375:4.5325, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%axis extensions
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.625, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.37pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{x});
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the `point meta`. I introduce an angle `\myangle` that determines the direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{30}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image, axis lines=center, ticks=none, view/h=120, view/v=20, enlarge x limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge y limits={abs=2pt}, enlarge z limits={abs=2pt}]

    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.65, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({-x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{-x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{-x});
%sphere
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, colormap={custom}{rgb255=(0,0,0)rgb255=(250,250,250)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 50,
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:180, y domain = 0:360] ({2*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {2*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {2*cos(v)});
%viviani window underlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%viviani cylinder parts
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta={cos(\myangle)*x+sin(\myangle)*y},
    colormap={custom}{rgb255=(255,255,255)rgb255=(100,100,100)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = -2:0, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {min(-sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
    \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta={cos(\myangle)*x+sin(\myangle)*y},
     colormap={custom}{rgb255=(255,255,255)rgb255=(100,100,100)}, z buffer = sort, samples = 35, 
    variable = \u, variable y = \v, domain = 0:360, y domain = 0:2, ] ({1+cos(u)}, {sin(u)}, {max(sqrt(4 - 2*x),v)});
%viviani window overlay edge
    \addplot3+[domain=-pi/3:2*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=5*pi/3:8*pi/3, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
    \addplot3+[domain=2.34375:4.5325, samples=50, samples y=0, no marks, smooth, solid, black, thin]({1+cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))},{2*sin(deg(x)/2)});
%axis extensions
    \addplot3+[domain=2:3.625, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({x},{0},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.4, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.31pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{x},{0});
    \addplot3+[domain=2:2.25, samples=5, samples y=0, line width= 0.37pt, no marks, smooth, solid, black]({0},{0},{x});
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you set this angle to 110 you get

[image]

Comment: I tried to make different shadings for the two surfaces but it seems that is not possible as they somehow interfere with each other.
Do you know how to workaround this?

Comment: @JackTigerLam Could you please post a new question that has the code that you have tried?